# How to add hooks for Mercurial MQ commands?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-queue

I would like to setup hg hooks for some actions done by mq extension. For example when I do

```
hg qnew
```

I would like to use post-review to create a new review request in our reviewboard server. I would also like to make a hook that updates the diff if you do

```
hg qrefresh
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All Mercurial commands have both a `pre-XXX` and `post-XXX` hook. So you can write write hooks like:

```
[hooks]
post-qnew.reviewboard = post-review $(hg root)/.hg/patches/$(hg qtip)
post-qrefresh.reviewboard = post-review $(hg root)/.hg/patches/$(hg qtip)
```

or whatever the correct post-review invocation is.

All examples approximate. :)